# A and B can do a piece of work in 9 days, B and C in 12 days, A and C in 18 days. If all of them work together, then how much time will they take?

Tags: arithmetic

This is how I did it.

$A+B=9  \tag 1$ 
$B+C=12  \tag 2$ 
$A+C=18  \tag 3$

Adding (1), (2) and (3) we get:

$A+B+B+C+A+C=9+12+18$ 
$2(A+B+C)=39$ 
$A+B+C=19.5$

So, they complete the work together in $19.5$ days.

**But the book says this answer is wrong and the correct solution is:**

Work done by $(A+B)$ in $1$ day = $\frac {1}{9}$ 
Work done by $(B+C)$ in $1$ day = $\frac {1}{12}$ 
Work done by $(A+C)$ in $1$ day = $\frac {1}{18}$

$(A+B)+(B+C)+(A+C)= \frac {1}{9} + \frac {1}{12} + \frac {1}{18}$ 
$A+B+C=\fracBE
 {1}{8}$
BE

So, all of them take $8$ days to complete the task.

**Could anybody please tell me why my approach is wrong and the book's approach is right?**

Comment: SO if $C$ stays home it takes $9$ days.  But if $C$ comes in any helps it will take ten days longer.  Just what is it that $C$ does that makes it take ten days longer.  Does she break windows?  Does she wander into the street and require a baby sitter?  Note: when two people work together it should take *less* time and not more time.  But *adding* is definitely *NOT* the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you *adding* them?

If I can clean a room it $2$ hours and you can clean a room in $3$ does it make sense to thing if we work together it would take us $5$ hours?  Why would you helping me make it take $3$ hours *longer*?  Shouldn't your helping me make it go *faster*?

So why are you adding the time?

So if we don't add what do we do?

Well, how many rooms can I clean in a day?  It takes $2$ hours per room and I have $24$ hours... that is $\frac {24}2=12$ rooms.  And how many room can you clean in a day?  It take you $3$ hours per room you can clean $\frac{24}3=8$ rooms.  So together how many room can we do?  Well, I can do $12$ any you can do $8$ so together we can to $20$.

Note:  YOu don't add how *long* it takes you! you add how much work you can do in an ammount of time!

And if it takes us $24$ hours to do $20$ rooms how long does it take us to do *$1$* room?  Well $\frac {24}{20} = 1.2$.  So together it takes us $1.2$ hours to do one rooom.  Notice that is *less* time than either of us.

So ... how do we do this if we don't want to just guess?

If I can do a job in $m$ time.  Then I can to $\frac 1m$ of the job in one unit of time.  And you can do a job in $n$ time then you can do a $\frac 1n$ of the job in one unit of time.  Togethere we can do $\frac 1m + \frac n = \frac {n+m}{mn}$ of the job in $1$ unit of time.

So how many units of time does it take to do the whole job?  We need $x$ units of time and we can to $\frac {n+m}{nm}\cdot x = 1$ job the those units of time so it takes us $x = \frac {nm}{n+m}$ time to do one job.

Ex:  If I take $2$ hours I can do $\frac 12$ a job in an hour.  You take $3$ hours so you can do $\frac 13$ a job in an hour.  Together we can do $\frac 12 + \frac 13 = \frac 56$ of the job in an hour.  After $x$ hours we can to $\frac 56 x$ jobs.  To do one job exactly we have $\frac 56 x = 1$ so $x = \frac 65=1.2$ hours.

So your problem.  $A$ and $B$ together take $9$ days.  so Together $A$ and $B$ can to $\frac 19$ of the job in $1$ day.  $B$ and $C$ together can do the job in $12$ days so together they can do $\frac 1{12}$ of the job in $1$ day.  And $A$ and $C$ together can do the job in $18$ days$ so together they can do $\frac 1{18}$ of the job in $1$ day.

If you cloned them all and had two copies of them working together then 2$Anne$s and 2$Bernie$s and 2$Claudia$s can do $\frac 1{9} + \frac 1{12} + \frac 1{18} = \frac 4{36} + \frac 3{36} +\frac 2{36} = \frac 9{36} = \frac 14$.  So two copies of the three people can do $\frac 14$ of the work in a day.

So one copy of the three people to do $\frac 12\frac 14 = \frac 18$ of the work in a day.

So how many days does it take to do on full job if the can do $\frac 18$ in a day? Then in $x$ days then can do $\frac 18 x = 1$ job.  SO $x = 8$ it takes them eight days working together.

Answer (score 2):

Here your variables $A,B,C$ doesn't exactly represent what you want them to. Your first equation is $A+B=9$ . Now this line says that $A$ is that certain amount of work done by the person A in those 9 days.
Your third equation is however $A+C=18$ , but here $A$ represents a different amount of work the person has done in 18 days and thus the ambiguity.

First we need to understand that a person's capability of doing a certain work in a given context is fixed per day. So let $W_A$ units be the amount of work A does in 1 day alone, similarly let $W_B , W_C$ be defined.

Now the work they are trying to complete is worth say $N$ units. As we have defined their capabilities in units, so this is consistent.

A and B can together do $W_A+W_B$ units of work in a day, so in 9 days they complete the work. This gives us :
$$ 9(W_A+W_B)=N$$
Similarly for others we have,
$$ 12(W_B+W_C) = N$$
$$ 18(W_C+W_A)=N$$
Work done by all three in one day is $(W_A+W_B+W_C)$ units , so if $X$ days are required for them to complete the work we must have ,
$$ X(W_A+W_B+W_C)=N$$
Now it is straightforward from here to find $X$ using basic algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that I like for this problem goes like so:

Imagine each of $A$, $B$, and $C$ has an identical twin, and all $6$ of the people go to work. In the $6$ people, we have one copy of each pair, $\{AB\}$, $\{AC\}$, and $\{BC\}$.

We will let them work for $36$ days, because $36=$lcm$(9,12,18)$.

In that time, $\{AB\}$ will complete $4$ jobs, $\{AC\}$ will complete $2$ jobs, and $\{BC\}$ will complete $3$ jobs. All together that is $9$ jobs in $36$ days, or $4$ days per job.

But since there are two of each person they can work twice as fast as normal. Thus $A$, $B$, and $C$ working together will complete a job in $8$ days.

Answer (score 1):

When you wrote your three equations you have not clearly thought what you want to say with them. This kind of problem requires a careful choice of the used units and meanings of the unknowns.

Assume that $A$, $B$, and $C$ as single persons can do the fractions $a$, $b$, $c$ of the "piece of work" in one day. (The numbers $a$, $b$, $c$ are $\ll1$.) The first equation then would say
$$a+b={1\over 9}\ ,$$
because $A$ and $B$ together need $9$ days to complete it all. Similarly we get
$$b+c={1\over12},\qquad a+c={1\over18}\ .$$
Adding these three equations gives
$$2(a+b+c)={1\over9}+{1\over12}+{1\over18}={1\over4}\ ,$$
or $\>a+b+c={1\over8}$. This says that all three together can do ${1\over8}$ of the total work in one day. Therefore the three will need $8$ days to do the "piece of work".